# Visual Studio 2013 Diff Tool

Tags: visual-studio-2013, diff

I'm used to edit files in Visual Studio 2013 Professional (update 3) using diff tool with *auto-synchronize* option enabled. Recently I'm not able to edit my local files anymore: they correctly appears in my *Pending Changes* view, but the second I compare them with my previous version (no matter if workspace or server) a small lock appears in the tab (eg: *Diff - MyFile.cpp [Lock]*)

Any idea how to fix it?

If I try to save my file it seems a copy is saved in my *temp* folder with the extension *- Copy*

Comment: yes, I can edit every file from standard editor (and every file goes to *pending changes*). my issue happens just from diff tool

Comment: Is the lock only there while the diff is open?

Comment: @drneel yes, just in the diff tool editor

Answer (score -1):

You might try updating VS2013. I have update 5 now and the diff tool seems to work reliably there.

I also found the diff tool to get somewhat flakey after a while when I was using the command line to launch it. I'm guessing that after enough bad input some prefs file would get botched and it would simply fail silently. Reinstalling the update would solve the problem, but that's a rather time-consuming process. Now that I use the VSCommands extension from Visual Studio Gallery to launch the diff tool it works reliably.

However, I'm having a similar problem as yours when I use the /m switch to do a merge of unversioned local files. A little lock icon appears on the file tab, even though I can "edit" in the GUI. However, saving doesn't save anything, and closing a dirty file just throws away the changes without even prompting! It's driving me nuts, because I can edit the same files successfully with the diff tool. Any help appreciated!